# How to replace NaN values in cells with a different random value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill empty cells from a single column (and then from multiple columns) using the standard deviation. I have seen several explanations but so far haven't seen any that is straightforward and pertinent to this question. Thank you in advance for your time!

Here is what I have so far:

To obtain random values, I first calculated the mean for the Math column:

```
filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'exam.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(filename)

math_mean = data['Math'].mean()
print(math_mean)
The output of that is 73.625
```

Then, I calculated the Standard deviation:

```
math_std = data['Math'].std()
print(math_std)
```

Which gave me `10.14097064951308` for STD.

```
73-10 = 63
73+10 = 83
```

Based on the calculation above, I need to generate random values between 63 and 83 and fill in the empty cells of the Math column. I used np.random.randint() to get the random values:

```
random_grades = np.random.randint(63,83)
print(random_grades)
```

So everything is fine so far, and the random values do get inserted into the empty cells. However, it's the same value repeating over and over.

I'm using this syntax:

```
#Producing random age values
random_grades = np.random.randint(63.48, 83.76)
print(random_grades)

#Storing new random ages to variable
new_grades = data.Math.fillna(random_grades)
print(new_grades)

#Passing new values to table
data['Math'].fillna(new_grades,inplace=True)
print(data)
```

This is the output:

```
0     79.0
1     82.0
2     85.0
3     77.0 # random value
4     70.0
5     77.0 # same random value
6     84.0
7     67.0
8     77.0 # same random value
9     63.0
10    59.0
```

If I try to add the parameter size= in `random_grades = np.random.randint(63.48, 83.76, size=5)` I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Desktop/tiny.py", line 88, in <module>
    new_grades = data.Math.fillna(random_grades)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4433, in fillna
    return super().fillna(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 6397, in fillna
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar, dict or Series, but you passed a "ndarray"
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Python evaluation your random function once and the apply it. What you need to do is find the count of NA `N`, then generate `randomN = np.random.randint(63.48, 83.76, N)` then apply `data.loc[lambda d: d['Math'].isna(), 'Math'] = randomN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `apply` for different values

```
df.Math = df.Math.apply(lambda x: np.random.randint(63.48, 83.76) if pd.isna(x) else x)
```

Comment: That was a beautiful solution.

Comment: @RobinSage Do approve the solution :)

Answer (score 4):

First idea is test missing values and assign length of random values count by number (by sum with `True = 1` and `False = 0`) of missing values by `N` parameter in [`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html):

```
mean = data['Math'].mean()
std = data['Math'].std()

mask = data['Math'].isna()
data.loc[mask, 'Math'] = np.random.randint(mean - std, mean + std, mask.sum())
```

Your solution is similar, only is converted numpy array to `Series` with index for missing values:

```
mean = data['Math'].mean()
std = data['Math'].std()

#Testing missing values
mask = data['Math'].isna()

#Producing random age values
random_grades = np.random.randint(mean - std, mean + std, mask.sum())
print(random_grades)

#convert array to Series and replace missing values
data['Math'] = data.Math.fillna(pd.Series(random_grades, index=data.index[mask]))
print(data)
```

Comment: Hey jezrael, Thank you for helping! Alright, lemme reproduce this here. I'll get back to you shortly!

Comment: @RobinSage - First solution is good for performance, second is a bit complicated. If performance not important is possible use loops in `apply` solution.

Comment: That worked really well. Now I don't know which answer to approve as both are great. I tried to use loops in the first answer, but it was a disaster. I'm getting confused with the Pandas syntax all the time. Frustrating...

Comment: @RobinSage - ya, pandas is vectorized, so best avoid loops. And `apply` or `applymap` or `for` or `itertuples` or `iterrows` are all loops. If possible, better not use them.

Comment: @RobinSage you can approve either solution you used. Ultimately, we are all here to help. Don't be stress out for approving haha :D

Answer (score 0):

```
np.random.randint(63.48, 83.76)
```

generates a single value, whereas-

```
np.random.randint(63.48, 83.76, 5)
```

generates **5 random values** within the limits specified.

Comment: Hey Agnij, thank for chiming in.  I tried doin that before, but I get an error. See my updated question, please.

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is generate a list of random variables and then select the number at random. as for the last bit, you replace the dataframe column by simply **data['Math'] = new_grades**